# duplicates lines after update

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Sometimes, when i want edit line in table(db) , this line duplicates: the old line remains and new(edited) appears. But sometimes its work correct. Why? Thanks.

Angular request:

```
   this.http.put('api/data/update', JSON.stringify(this.tabl1.filter(x => x.p1 == e.key)),
    {   headers: new HttpHeaders({
        "Content-Type": "application/json"})  
    }).subscribe(data => (console.log(data)));
```

Controller method:

```
[HttpPut]
public IActionResult update([FromBody] RaschetDoppokazR1[] obj)
    {
        try
        { 
          if (obj != null)
          {
            db.RaschetDoppokazR1.UpdateRange(obj);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Json("OK");
          }
          else return Json("null");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            return Json("Exception");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where are the lines appearing ? in the DB or in the browser ?

Comment: in DB of course

Comment: Then you don't need an Angular tag, since it's a .NET issue.

Comment: In general, if there is no primary key for `RaschetDoppokazR1` record, it will create a new record instead of update existing records. Share and check `obj` value to see whether all the records have value for `Id`. Share us the json string for `JSON.stringify(this.tabl1.filter(x => x.p1 == e.key)`

Comment: Thanks Edward , i found my error: when i add new line to db , primary key there generating by the function , and if i try update line without updating my data, record will sent without primary key. But now i  have another problem: when i update(with request) my data new lines doesnt displays, until i don't update with f5(i use devextreme treelist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when i add new line to db , primary key there generating by the function , and if i try update line without updating my data, record will sent without primary key.